Render Gazebo model in web interface
From the portal https://app.gazebosim.org/fuel I see that 3D previews of the selected model are proposed. Analysing the page source I see that this preview is done with three.js.
I therefore wanted to ask if it is possible to use an sdf model for Gazebo to a representation for a web interface. Is Three.js the only solution? Is there an automatic way to do the conversion from sdf to a format for Three.js?
Is it possible instead to implement a way to visualize an instance of Gazebo (Ignition Fortress) in a web page so that, also the physics is considered and, I can actually see the movements of the robots that are received by the Gazebo ROS2 node, exactly like the Gazebo view?
Thanks for the information

Have you already checked some of the options on https://robotwebtools.github.io/ ? e.g., ros3djs? And yes, there is https://github.com/gazebo-web/gzweb

Thank you for your response. I have seen some examples on robotwebtools.github.io, but many are not working. Also the rest of the material, like the one you mentioned, seems to me to refer to ROS1 and then Gazebo Classic. Could you recommend some working examples with ROS2 and Gazebo Ignition embedded into a custom web page? Thank you very much

You could use ros-tool* to get the data into the browser, and then use three.js directly (or via ros3djs if that is still working) to visualize it. For loading into three.js I would look at the available loaders (https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/loaders), and see which of these it would be easiest to convert the SDF into.
Alternatively, even of ros3djs may not be working anymore, you could probably still use their URDF to three.js converter: https://github.com/RobotWebTools/ros3djs/blob/develop/src/urdf/Urdf.js
* Disclaimer: I'm the author of that component, but it's free.

Thank you for your suggestion. I will try also with this way!
